# A fair die is rolled nine times. What is the probability that 1 appears three times, 2 and 3 each appear twice, 4 and 5 once and 6 not at all?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, dice

A fair die is rolled nine times. What is the probability that 1 appears three times, 2 and 3 each appear twice, 4 and 5 once and 6 not at all?

---

My approach is fairly simple. The dice is  fair, so we have a total of $6^9$ possible strings. Consider the set $\{1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5\}$. From this set is a total possible number of combinations of

$$\frac{9!}{3!2!2!}=30240$$

Thus, the probability of the above occuring is $30240/6^9$

My question is whether or not I have properly accounted for the probability of $4$ and $5$, and whether or not I should account for their probabilty of being rolled by considering the probability of **never** rolling a $6$.

Could someone explain why I should or should not have these concerns?

Comment: Your answer is correct, exepted for the fact that $$\frac{9!}{3! 2! 2!} = 15120$$

Comment: I think the total possible number of combinations can be reinterpreted as $$\frac{9!}{3!2!2!1!1!0!}$$. Note that $1! = 1$ and $0! = 1$.

Comment: Maybe you could think of 9!/(3!2!2!) as (9 choose 3) times (6 choose 2) times (4 choose 2) times (2 choose 1) times (1 choose 1) times (0 choose 0).  Where you are writing a length 9 sequence and choosing the positions to assign the values {1,2,3,4,5,6}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct, other than getting your computation wrong. Check wythatoras' comment for the correct value.

As there is only a single instance of 4 and 5 in the permuted set, 9! does not double count on the possible positions of 4 or 5.
The probability of never rolling 6 is similarly accounted for- if you roll three 1s, two 2s, two 3s, a 4 and a 5, no dice remain unrolled. If all the other conditions are satisfied, not rolling a 6 comes automatically.